# More extensive mangling terser-webpack-plugin?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, terser

Is there a way to thoroughly mangle `vue` components that have been bundled with `webpack`?

When applying mangling via [`terser-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/) with `mangle.properties` set to `true`, then not all of the property names are mangled, for example:

```
location: {
  lng: -.134281,
  lat:51.513508,
  zoom:13,
  pitch:1,
  bearing:60
}
```

becomes

```
location:{
  k:-.134281,
  M:51.513508,
  zoom:13,
  pitch:1,
  V:60
}
```

### Edit

As requested: the relevant portion of the Webpack configuration file, in this case the default `vie-cli` config with the `mangle.properties` item manually added:

```
minimizer: [
      {
        options: {
          test: /\.m?js(\?.*)?$/i,
          chunkFilter: () => true,
          warningsFilter: () => true,
          extractComments: false,
          sourceMap: false,
          cache: true,
          cacheKeys: defaultCacheKeys => defaultCacheKeys,
          parallel: true,
          include: undefined,
          exclude: undefined,
          minify: undefined,
          terserOptions: {
            output: {
              comments: /^\**!|@preserve|@license|@cc_on/i
            },
            compress: {
              arrows: false,
              collapse_vars: false,
              comparisons: false,
              computed_props: false,
              hoist_funs: false,
              hoist_props: false,
              hoist_vars: false,
              inline: false,
              loops: false,
              negate_iife: false,
              properties: false,
              reduce_funcs: false,
              reduce_vars: false,
              switches: false,
              toplevel: false,
              typeofs: false,
              booleans: true,
              if_return: true,
              sequences: true,
              unused: true,
              conditionals: true,
              dead_code: true,
              evaluate: true
            },
            mangle: {
              safari10: true,
              properties: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
```

Comment: Can you please post the webpack optimization config for this.

Comment: @jom added the relevant section from the config file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two properties (`zoom`, `pitch`) so happened to be included in the [`reserved`](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#mangle-options) name list, have a look at this default [`domprops.json`](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/blob/master/tools/domprops.json) file which UglifyJS uses internally during mangling.

> A default exclusion file is provided in `tools/domprops.json` which should cover most standard JS and DOM properties defined in various browsers. Pass `--mangle-props` domprops to disable this feature

If you like to keep this default list, you could do any of the following in the [custom minify option](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/#custom-minify-function) of the plugin:

1. Create your custom reserved name list,
2. Load up the default list (`domprops.json`) and pass in a function/filter for removing those unwanted names,
3. Simply merge these two files if you are sure there is no name conflict.

#### webpack.config.js

```js
{
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        minify(file, sourceMap) {
          const uglifyJsOptions = {
            mangle: {
              properties: {
                reserved: require('your_custom_list')
              }

              // Or filter them

              properties: {
                reserved: require('uglify-js/tools/domprops.json')
                  .filter(name => ![
                    'zoom',
                    'pitch'
                  ]
                  .includes(name))
              }
            }
          };

          return require('uglify-js').minify(file, uglifyJsOptions);
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
}
```

Also, please mind the similarities between `mangle.reserved` and `mangle.properties.reserved` while doing this, as the latter one might be what you need here. Check out the [minify option structure](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#minify-options-structure).

Comment: thanks for the info, and good to know about the domprops file.

Comment: is there a way to only mangle specific files? I am running into a lot of issues where mangling affects imported libraries.

Comment: Not quite sure about that, but you could probably try specifying a regexp pattern in the loader's rule targeting specific (set of) files.